# Apply Mailbox rule created by EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've written a small code block, that creates the following rule in my mailbox:

- Apply this rule after the message arrives
- when received before [Current Date - X days]
- delete it.

This is the corresponding code block:

```
var exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
DateTime dtOldestDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(iDays * -1);
exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials(sUser, sPassword);
exchange.AutodiscoverUrl(sUser);
if (exchange != null)
{
    RuleCollection InboxRules = exchange.GetInboxRules(sUser);
    bool bRuleFound = false;
    foreach (Rule InboxRule in InboxRules)
    {
        if (InboxRule.DisplayName == "MailboxCleaner: Deletion Policy")
        {
            bRuleFound = true;
            InboxRule.Conditions.WithinDateRange.Start = null;
            InboxRule.Conditions.WithinDateRange.End = dtOldestDate;

            SetRuleOperation setRuleOperation = new SetRuleOperation(InboxRule);
            exchange.UpdateInboxRules(new RuleOperation[] { setRuleOperation }, true);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!bRuleFound)
    {
        Rule NewInboxRule = new Rule();
        NewInboxRule.DisplayName = "MailboxCleaner: Deletion Policy";
        NewInboxRule.Priority = 1;
        NewInboxRule.IsEnabled = true;
        NewInboxRule.Conditions.WithinDateRange.Start = null;
        NewInboxRule.Conditions.WithinDateRange.End = dtOldestDate;
        NewInboxRule.Actions.PermanentDelete = true;
        CreateRuleOperation createOperation = new CreateRuleOperation(NewInboxRule);
        exchange.UpdateInboxRules(new RuleOperation[] { createOperation },  true);
    }

    // How can I go on and apply this rule on all messages?
}
```

At the second last line i'd like to apply my new / modified rule. I need to do this, as the rule will be applied in another way. Outlook therefor has the following button:

[image: "Run Rules Now..."-Button]

*(Picture lent from https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2015/05/01/client-side-vs-server-side-rules/)*

Can I somehow trigger the same procedure by using EWS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't.. I had to write an entire application that uses EWS to login and process the required messages.